# How i can convert a txt to int in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

i have a txt file with this :

> 1230;
>   012;
>   45;
>   125

and i want to convert this in an int 
but is doesn't work... he juste return the last number
here is my code :

```
$numbertxt = get-content -Path C:\mysticpath\number.txt -Raw 
$numbertxt.GetType()
write-host $numbertxt
foreach ($flags in $numbertxt)
{
    $integer = [int]$flags
}
echo $integer
```

somebody can help me ?

Sorry for my english

Comment: Your `echo` is outside of the loop... so it only returns the last value

Comment: What are you trying to do with them where they need to be `[int]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$numbertxt = (get-content -Path C:\mysticpath\number.txt -Raw) -split ';'
$numbertxt.GetType()
write-host $numbertxt
foreach ($flags in $numbertxt)
{
    $integer = [int]$flags
    echo $integer
}
```

First a integer can only be made of numbers so you will need to split the contents by ';'. This will make a array of strings that are numbers.

Also put the echo on the inside of the for loop will allow for it to display each number as its processed

Answer (score 0):

try this method (control if it's convertible to integer before print)

```
$res=0;

#verbose version
(Get-Content "c:\temp\test.txt") -split ';' | where {[int]::TryParse($_, [ref] $res)} | foreach {$res}

#short version
(gc "c:\temp\test.txt") -split ';' | ?{[int]::TryParse($_, [ref] $res)} | %{$res}
```